# How to set Tags for DynamoDb in serverless.yml

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I want to set tags for Dynamo DB, did we have a serverless.yml configuration for it like we have it for function

```
functions:
  createUsers:
    tags:
      key: value
```

Answer (score 5):

```
resources:
  Resources:
    DynamoDbTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:

    TableName: 'table'
    AttributeDefinitions:
      -
        AttributeName: id
        AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        Tags:
            - 
              Key: 'tagKey'
              Value: 'tagValue'
```